# Why stream don't throw RuntimeException?

Tags: java

Test method always throw RuntimeException. And I can catch the RuntimeException

```
void test() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

```
System.out.println("start");
try {    
    test();
}
catch(RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
System.out.println("end");
```

This codes show the below result.

> start
> java.lang.RuntimeException
> end

But, In a stream, I can't catch the RuntimeException.

```
System.out.println("start");
try {    
    nums.stream().map((num) -> {
        test();
        return null;
    });
}
catch(RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
System.out.println("end");
```

This codes show the below result.

> start
> end

Why I can't catch the RuntimeException in stream.

Comment: You don't have a terminal operation, so the stream is never evaluated. Try adding `.forEach(num -> {});` after the `map` (or use `forEach` instead of `map`). (I'm also assuming `nums` is non-empty).

Comment: There has to be a good canonical "because you don't have a terminal operation" target question...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, you'd think.

Comment: Thank you. After adding ".collect(Collectors.toList())", I can catch the RuntimeExceptino.

Comment: @Lino good find.

Comment: @Lino maybe I just didn't think far enough away from the phrase "terminal operation"... :)

Answer (score 3):

As it says in [the Javadoc of the `java.util.stream` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (emphasis added):

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. **Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.**

[`map` is an intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), and you don't have a terminal operation. As such, the pipeline source is not traversed.

Change `map` to `forEach` (and remove the `return`):

```
nums.stream().forEach((num) -> {
    test();
});
```

(I assume also that `nums` is non-empty).